# discord.js | Bot doesn't tag my channel(undefined)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, undefined, mention

I made a purge/clear command for my discord bot, but when I do /purge amount: (amount), it works fine, but the bot replies with `️ (amount) messages were deleted from undefined.`, which should be `️ (amount) messages were deleted from #moderator-only.`. Is this because I don't have the correct intents or have I done something wrong? I have currently only the `SERVER MEMBERS` intent.

Code:

```
const { CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "purge",
    description: "Deletes a specific amount of messages from a target.",
    permissions: "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
    options: [
        {
            name: "amount",
            description: "Select the amount of messages to remove from the target.",
            type: "NUMBER",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "target",
            description: "Select the target to remove messages from.",
            type: "USER",
            required: false
        }
    ],
     /**
      * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
      */
    async execute(interaction) {
        const { channel, options } = interaction;

        const Amount = options.getNumber("amount");
        const Target = options.getMember("target");

        const Messages = await channel.messages.fetch();

        const Response = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#171717');

        if(Target) {
            let i = 0;
            const filtered = [];
            (await Messages).filter((m) => {
                if(m.author.id === Target.id && Amount > i) {
                    filtered.push(m);
                    i++;
                }
            })

            await channel.bulkDelete(filtered, true).then(messages => {
                Response.setDescription(`️ **${messages.size}** messages were deleted from ${Target}.`);
                interaction.reply({embeds: [Response]});
            })
        } else {
            await channel.bulkDelete(Amount, true).then(messages =>{
                Response.setDescription(`️ **${messages.size}** messages were deleted from ${channel.mention}.`);
                interaction.reply({embeds: [Response]});
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `channel`? Does it really have a `mention` property?

Comment: It is the `#moderator-only` channel for discord community servers, but I also tried it in normal channels, but it keeps saying `undefined` .

Comment: Discord has different types of chanels. Such as `ThreadChannel`, `TextChannel`, `NewsChannel`. All three of those have a `.bulkDelete()` function. Assuming it's a [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel), it doesn't have a `mention` property, so it is `undefined`. You'll need to find out where that mention comes from. (I'm not a Discord expert, but it sounds like something that belongs to a message instead of a channel.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `channel.mention` is not a thing in discord.js.

```js
.setDescription(`️ **${messages.size}** messages were deleted from ${channel}.`);
```

OR

```js
.setDescription(`️ **${messages.size}** messages were deleted from <#${channel.id}>.`);
```

- Either of the above ways will work. The first is mentioning the channel directly, and the second is using the channel's ID to mention.